# Application build . (Swift on Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, swift, ubuntu, build, package-managers

I am a total newbie to programming and Ubuntu and Swift is my first language to learn.

I am learning with a book but I encountered a problem when I was supposed to build an application. Here is what I had to do:

Make a new directory called PMExample so that's easy `mkdir PMExample`
and then go to this directory `cd PMExample`.

Then I had to use `~/swift package init` and got 2 directories called Sources and Tests and a file Package.swift.
 So in the Sources folder there was one text file and I had to create another one to build an application.

And I did all those steps correctly, but now there is a problem. The book tells me to use `swift build` command. The book says that this will build the application and if all is well, I will have an executable application in the
`PMExample/.build/debug` directory named PMExample...

But after `~/swift build` while being in the PMExample dir, there isn't any new directory called .build or anything. There are no errors popping up after using that `~/swift build` command. Just nothing happens and I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But after ~/swift build while being in the PMExample dir, there isn't any new directory called .build or anything.

How do you know that? It is likely that you are not seeing the directory because it starts with a dot (it is called `.build`), therefore it is not shown by default with `ls`. You have to pass the `-a` argument to `ls`, such as in:

```
ls -a PMExample
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
It occurs that when I have run the build command ubuntu just didnt even start to execute it, but I managed to run it this time (I dont know how) and I can see the files thanks to your tip. Thank you again and have a good day!